# There is no row in position 1 but in debug mode it is correctly mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I am trying to fill a DataTable using a parameter from a TextBox. Then I want to take the values from the DataTable and fill the rest of the text boxes on the WebForm. As of now I am testing it so I only want two TextBoxes to get filled because I still need to validate the others. The code I am using is this:

```
try
{
    ItemsSetTableAdapters.AbileneTableAdapter ds = new ItemsSetTableAdapters.AbileneTableAdapter();
    ItemsSet.AbileneDataTable dt = new ItemsSet.AbileneDataTable();
    ds.Fill(dt, TxtItem.Text);
    con = true;

    if (con == true)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            TxtItem.Text = dt.Rows[0]["t_item"].ToString();
            lbldesc.Text = dt.Rows[1]["t_idsc"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (IfxException ifx)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ifx.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Source:" + ifx.Source);
    Console.WriteLine(ifx.StackTrace);
}
```

The error I am getting is there is no row at position 1 and I looked at the table, columns and list in debug mode and its is mapped correctly like [1] = [t_idsc]. Why am I getting this error? Please help me out.

Fixed my issue but just wanted to clarify something real quick:

this was the code i had before to perform the same functionality what is wrong with this??

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         TxtItem.Text = dt.Rows[0]["t_item"].ToString();
         lbldesc.Text = dt.Rows[1]["t_idsc"].ToString();
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a row at position 1, but you may not have a row at position 2. Remember that the rows collection is zero based. So when you do this:

```
TxtItem.Text = dt.Rows[0]["t_item"].ToString();
lbldesc.Text = dt.Rows[1]["t_idsc"].ToString();
```

You are setting `TxtItem.Text` to "t_item" of the first row. But you are setting `lbldesc.Text` to "t_idsc" of the *second* row.

Instead, use the row variable from your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    TxtItem.Text = row["t_item"].ToString();
    lbldesc.Text = row["t_idsc"].ToString();
}
```

Please do note that those labels will have their value overwritten for each DataRow you have in your DataTable. So what you will see in those labels is the values for the *last* row in your DataTable. You may need to rework your logic because of this.

If you wanted to just grab the values of the first row, you could simply hardcode the row number of the first row, 0, as the index of your rows collection.

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    TxtItem.Text = dt.Rows[0]["t_item"].ToString();
    lbldesc.Text = dt.Rows[0]["t_idsc"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: in my question i have attached to another approach but i still got the same error so could you please clarify to me what went wrong there please buddy.

Comment: Sort of, but not exactly. See my edit above. When you are using the `foreach` loop, the loop gives you a `DataRow`. Without the loop, you need to get the `DataRow` yourself (i.e. `dt.Rows[0]`).

Comment: It seems as though you deleted a comment. My first comment was addressed to that. To your second comment - using `dt.Rows[0]`, the `[0]` part tells it you want index 0 of your rows collection, also known as the first row. `[1]` says you want index 1 of your rows collection, or the second row. Since you don't have a second row, it throws an error.